# Transponer datos de consulta en mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo esta tabla en mysql (Los registros son dinamicos):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito mostrar los datos en la consulta sql de esta manera :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo puedes solucionarlo con una tabla pivote

Comment: como se hace una tabla pivote? @JuanCarlos

Comment: Puedes encontrar mucha ayuda en este link:

http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78

cualquier adicional a la orden